# Mockito ClassCastException with casting field

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I'm trying to write unit test for the following code:

```
 public DesiredCapabilities findCapability(Platforms platform, Types type, String browser, double platformVersion) throws Exception{
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(BrowserCapabilities.class)
                                    .add(Restrictions.eq("status", ICommonConstants.DB_STATUS_ACTIVE))
                                    .add(Restrictions.eq("platformName", platform.getValue()))
                                    .add(Restrictions.eq("browserName", browser))
                                    .add(Restrictions.eq("platformVersion", platformVersion))
                                    .addOrder(Order.desc("browserVersion"))
                                    .setMaxResults(1);

    Object res = criteria.uniqueResult();
    if(res!=null)
        return this.prepareBrowserCapability((BrowserCapabilities)res);

    return null;
}
```

The mock code is:

```
private BrowserCapabilityDAO mockBrowserCapability;
private Session mockSession;
private Criteria mockCriteria;
private Criterion mockCriterion;


@Before
public void init() {
    mockBrowserCapability = Mockito.spy(new BrowserCapabilityDAO());
    mockSession = Mockito.mock(Session.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    mockCriteria = Mockito.mock(Criteria.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    mockCriterion = Mockito.mock(Criterion.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
}


@Test
public void testFindCapability() throws Exception {

    DesiredCapabilities desiredCapability = new DesiredCapabilities();
    BrowserCapabilities mockBrowserCapabilities = getMockBrowserCapabilities();

    //Stub
    Mockito.doReturn(mockSession).when(mockBrowserCapability).getSession();
    Mockito.when(mockSession.createCriteria(Mockito.eq(BrowserCapabilities.class))).thenReturn(mockCriteria);
    Mockito.doReturn(mockCriteria).when(mockCriteria).add(mockCriterion);
    Mockito.when(mockCriteria.addOrder(Mockito.any(Order.class))).thenReturn(mockCriteria);
    Mockito.when(mockCriteria.setMaxResults(Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(mockCriteria);
    Mockito.when(mockCriteria.uniqueResult()).thenReturn((Object)mockBrowserCapabilities);
    //Mockito.doReturn(desiredCapability).when(mockBrowserCapability).prepareBrowserCapability(mockBrowserCapabilities);

    mockBrowserCapability.findCapability(Platforms.WINDOWS, Types.COMPUTER, "FF", 10.0);
}

private BrowserCapabilities getMockBrowserCapabilities() {
    BrowserCapabilities mockBrowserCapabilities = new BrowserCapabilities();
    mockBrowserCapabilities.setBrowserName("browserName");
    mockBrowserCapabilities.setBrowserVersion("browserVersion");
    return mockBrowserCapabilities;
}
```

But I'm getting the `ClassCastException` at line:

```
return this.prepareBrowserCapability((BrowserCapabilities)res);
```

cannot be cast to `com.common.xxx.persistence.beans.BrowserCapabilities`.

Comment: What's the source for `getMockBrowserCapabilities()`?

Comment: Added in the question.

Comment: Are you sure? I can't see it...

Comment: private BrowserCapabilities getMockBrowserCapabilities() {
  
  
  BrowserCapabilities mockBrowserCapabilities = new BrowserCapabilities();  
  
  mockBrowserCapabilities.setBrowserName("browserName");  
  mockBrowserCapabilities.setBrowserVersion("browserVersion");  
  
  return mockBrowserCapabilities;  
 }

Comment: Well, that's not a complicated method. Are you 100% sure the `BrowserCapabilities` class it returns is really `com.common.xxx.persistence.beans.BrowserCapabilities`?

Comment: yes the return type is of com.common.xxx.persistence.beans.BrowserCapabilities

Comment: Well, then change this line: `return this.prepareBrowserCapability((BrowserCapabilities)res);` to `return this.prepareBrowserCapability((com.common.xxx.persistence.beans.BrowserCapabilities)res);`

Comment: tried that, but the same result

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace, it's not clear who/what `cannot be cast to com.common.xxx.persistence.beans.BrowserCapabilities`. Also please use @username when replying to someone so they get notified when you answer to their comments.